# Problemas ao usar font-face no site

Tags: css, font, css-font-face, www

Eu estou usando font-face no meu site e ela carrega normalmente ao digitar o link com www.ksleague.com, porém, ao digitar o link sem o www, ele não puxa a font-face. Como devo resolver isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de usar o caminho inteiro dos `.css`, use o caminho relativo:

Em vez de `"http://www.ksleague.com/_css/component.css"`

Use `"_css/component.css"`

Isso porque ao usar o caminho inteiro, pode dar erro de "política de mesma origem" caso omitam o "www" no endereço do site.

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito e funcionou!

Comment: @MarcosFelipe Valeu! Sucesso!